# macOSでhttpd.confを編集してApacheを立ち上げるとForbidden応答が返ってくる

Tags: macos, apache

まず当方のシステム環境です。
macOS Sierra
Apache: 2.4.25 (Unix)
mysql: stable 5.7.19

サーバーを立ち上げ、

```
http://localhost/
```

へアクセスするも、

```
Forbidden　You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

エラーログは、

```
Cannot serve directory /users/ユーザー名/Sites/: 
No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html,index.html,index.php)found,     
and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

httpd.conf（変更点）

```
# LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so #コメントアウト
# LoadModule alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_alias.so #コメントアウト
# LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so #コメントアウト
# LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so #コメントアウト

DocumentRoot "/users/ユーザー名/Sites/"
 <Directory "/users/ユーザー名/Sites/">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
MultiviewsMatch Any

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Require all granted
```

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf #コメントアウト
```

ユーザ名.confも作成し、

```
/apache2/users/ユーザ名

<Directory "/Users/ユーザ名/Sites/">
AllowOverride All
Options Indexes MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

として入れてあります。

未熟な私に解決方法をご教授ください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 少しでも早く助けが欲しかったら、タイトルには「助けてください」なんて無駄な言葉は入れずに、「どんな環境・状態・設定で何をしたらどんな結果になったのか、本当はどうしたいのか」を簡潔にまとめるようにしてください。また本文を読んでも以下の点が不明です。・Apacheは外部パッケージからインストールされたのでしょうか、それもとSierraにインストール済みのものでしょうか？・httpd.confと「ユーザ名.conf」を変更の他にはどんな準備(設定の変更やらファイルの追加やら)をされましたか？・エラーログとhttpd.conf、「ユーザ名.conf」にある「yusuke3627」「ユーザ名」の部分は実際のシステムでは、あなたのmacのユーザ名に置き換えられているのでしょうか、それとも字面通り「ユーザ名」と言うカタカナ漢字の設定・ファイル名なのでしょうか？・同じく設定ファイル中の「users」の部分は大文字で始まる「Users」ではなく「users」で入力されているのでしょうか？・何かネット上の記事を参考にされたのであれば、そのリンクをご記載ください。

Comment: 設定で指定したドキュメントルート以下にコンテンツ(index.html等)は存在するのでしょうか。もしくは設定だけ済ませてファイルは何も存在しない状態でアクセスしている？

Comment: 情報のご提供ありがとうございます。しかしながら、`define('DB_H‌​OST', 'localhost');`のようなPHPのコードをhttpd.confに記載することはないはずです。正確な情報を追加してご経験を共有していただければ他の開発者にとっても有用な情報になるかと思いますので、情報を整理した上で回答として投稿していただければと思います。

Comment: @ OOPer @ cubick 記載内容に不備がありましたので訂正します。**wp-config.php**にあるdefine('DB_H‌​OST', 'localhost');からdefine('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');に変更することで立ち上げることができました。大変失礼しました。

Comment: 追加情報ありがとうございます。ただ、Word Pressをインストールされた旨は全くご質問中に記載していただいておりませんし、その変更が問題だった場合には、エラーログには **`No matching DirectoryIndex ...`** は出力されないだろうと思うのですが。そこに至るまでの経緯なども含めて、やはり回答の形でご解説いただければ、参考になる事柄がいろいろあるように思われます。お手数でしょうが、是非ご検討ください。

Comment: @ OOPer　ご回答ありがとうございます。至らぬ点ばかりで申し訳ないのですが、様々なコマンドを経て立ち上がったため詳しく把握できていないというのが現状です。。。次回投稿する際は有益な情報提供できますよう努めます。

Answer (score 1):

> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

はファイルシステム上のパーミッションの事を直接指しているわけではありません。その場合もありますが、Apacheでのアクセス制限や権限制限に引っかかった時に一般的に出るメッセージです。

今回の場合、エラーメッセージに

- DirectoryIndexで使われるindex.php、index.htmlが見つからない
- 一覧表示が禁止されている（Options Indexesがない）

と書いてあります。httd.confの方でOptionsにIndexesを追加するか、index.htmlまたはindex.phpを作成してください。

--

蛇足ですが、

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf #コメントアウト
```

コメントアウトしたのかしてないのか意味がわからないです。コメントアウトしたのであれば、

```
# Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf #コメントアウト
```

と実際にコメントアウトした状態を示す、してないのであれば

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf #コメントアウトを解除
```

など実態を反映したコメントにされるほうがよいです。

Comment: @ suzukis ご回答ありがとうございます。httpd.confにあるdefine('DB_H‌​OST', 'localhost');からdefine('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');に変更することで立ち上げることができました。コメントアウトの件、以後気をつけて記載致します。

Comment: 記載内容に不備がありましたので訂正します。wp-config.phpにあるdefine('DB_H‌​OST', 'localhost');からdefine('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');に変更することで立ち上げることができました。大変失礼しました。

Answer (score 0):

まず、以下のコマンドでディレクトリの存在確認とパーミッションを確認するとよいかと思います。

```
ls -lah /users/yusuke3627/Sites/
```

※それと ls コマンドでは通るようですが /users ではなく /Users と指定した方がよいかと思います。

パーミッションがないということなので、以下のコマンド等で指定ユーザーを確認し、ドキュメントルートの所有者を変更してみてはどうでしょうか。

```
httpd -t -D DUMP_CONFIG 2>/dev/null | grep "User "
chown -R www:www /Users/yusuke3627/Sites/
```

Comment: @ Bezeklik ご回答ありがとうございます。httpd.confにあるdefine('DB_H‌​OST', 'localhost');からdefine('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');に変更することで立ち上げることができました。またご指摘頂きました通りURLを修正しました。お手数をお掛けいたしました。

Comment: 記載内容に不備がありましたので訂正します。wp-config.phpにあるdefine('DB_H‌​OST', 'localhost');からdefine('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');に変更することで立ち上げることができました。大変失礼しました。